# Unable to install chef-server older version on centos manually

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra

I am on Centos 6.5 and would like to have chef-server version 10.30.4 as [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/chef-server).

I am using the ruby version of 1.9.3 via RVM. As on this [link](http://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-1-9-3-or-multiple-ruby-verson-on-centos-6-3-using-rvm).

and even after having installed all dependencies as on [this page](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef10/Installing+Chef+Server+Manually)

like

- CouchDB,  RabbitMQ,  Java,  GEOS,  zlib and libxml,  setting up the
  GPG key  and also tried the hammer method of yum groupinstall
  "Development Tools"

but getting the following errors on

```
gem install chef-server -v "10.30."
```

Note: all of these are being done as root.

Error is

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
>       no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=mixlib-authentication)

And by the way gem source rightly points

gem source
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/

There seems to have been some progress after I did

```
gem update
```

And now the error is

> ERROR:  Error installing chef-server:     ERROR: Failed to build gem
>   native extension.
>
> ```
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for main() in -lgecodesearch... no
> ```
>
> ========================================================================================= Gecode >3.5 must be installed (http://www.gecode.org/).

Comment: Is the Geocode-Library actually installed? Does the server have problems with resolving ip addresses? host api.rubygems.org

Comment: thanks for the reply @Mic92, yes when i tried to install the geocode it said that its already installed.

Comment: What is the output of: pkg-config --modversion gecode

Comment: my mistake gecode does not ship a pc file by default

Comment: At least a file called /usr/lib/libgecodesearch.so.35 should exists

Comment: thanks again @Mic92, that file is not available... not sure how to get it in though as this is a dependency for gecode

Comment: When i do a yum install gecode it says Trying other mirror.
Setting up Install Process
Package gecode-3.7.3-3.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version but when i try which gecode it says /usr/bin/which: no gecode in (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Comment: Is there a package like gecode-devel available? This package is installed in the gecode cookbook from opscode: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/gecode/blob/master/recipes/package.rb

Comment: Please format your question using code and block formatting. It will help ensure you get the best answers.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing chef 11? It is a significant improvement over chef 10.

http://docs.opscode.com/install_server.html

The new omnibus packaging means all you need to do is download a single RPM package and run the configure task:

```
sudo yum install https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-server-11.0.11-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark, the reason we wanted that version is, some documents claim knife-openstack is stable with Chef 10.30.2

Comment: I find that hard to believe, openstack is a very active project.... Having said that, I haven't used the openstack knife plugin :-(

Comment: Why the chef-server 11 is not available through rubygems?? I need to install on a 32bit system...

Comment: @brauliobo Chef server is no longer based on ruby. Chef 11 introduced a refactored solution implemented in Erlang. Even in the older days I don't think chef server was completely installable using rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

We had to abort this and installed Chef server using the omnibus install on CentOS 6.5 and seems like the document we were referring to way led us, knife-openstack works just fine with the 11X Chef series. 
Thanks to all those who tried to help us out.